# Comparing two tables where one column matches and the other doesn't

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to compare two tables based on two columns. I to see where the usernames match between the tables and the email addresses don't match.

Here is what I tried:

```
select * from ecy t1, users t2 where t1.username = t2.username and t1.email <> t2.email
```

When I run this I get all the users in the ecy table even if their emails are equal.

Thanks.

Comment: your query should produce the correct results. are you sure the emails are equal and there aren't any white spaces you're not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do the Cartesian Product of the two tables and try to filter it with the old Ansi way.

```
SELECT u.username, u.email
FROM users u
JOIN ecy e on e.email <> u.email AND u.username = e.username
```

you could also try doing it with a subquery select that is joined

```
SELECT username, email
FROM users u
JOIN( SELECT username, email FROM ecy) t on t.username = u.username and t.email <> u.email
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96126/1)

you want to use the JOIN syntax to join tables together and not do a Cartesian Product. the JOIN syntax will also allow you to filter out data as it joins

Comment: Not an optimal solution using sub queries

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid i added two more ways to do it

Comment: join solution makes sense

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, i didn't use <> before in mysql.

```
select * from ecy t1, users t2 where t1.username = t2.username and not t1.email = t2.email
```

Comment: <> means not equal to